# filtering date per factor group

Tags: r, date, filter, dplyr

i have this datasets

```
set.seed(1)
df1<- data.frame(
  user = as.factor(rep(c("mike","john","david", "gabriel"), each =4)),
  trx_date = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 16)
)

df2<- data.frame(
  user = as.factor(c("mike","john","david")),
  filter_date= as.Date(c("1999-07-29", "1999-03-08", "1999-10-24"))
```

how do i filter any `trx_date` in `df1` which happen after `filter_date` in `df2` per `user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the package `dplyr`, you could do

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(df1, df2, by=c('user')) %>%
  group_by(user) %>%
  filter(trx_date >= filter_date)
```

But what do you want to do with "gabriel"? It does not exist in df2, so how should that be filtered? With the above solution, it is lost. If you want to keep it, replace `filter` with `filter(trx_date >= filter_date | is.na(filter_date))`. (Note the use of a single `|` as opposed to the usual `||`)

Comment: i want to filter that out too. so my result df will be without "gabriel". appreciate for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can join the two dataframes and then `filter` :

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  inner_join(df2, by = 'user') %>%
  filter(trx_date > filter_date)
```

Comment: appreciate for the help sir

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can use `merge` with `subset`

```
subset(merge(df1, df2, by = 'user'), trx_date > filter_date)
```